# Robin sharma's following rivals that of Dalai Lama's meaning?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I came across below statement in one of the book

> Robin sharma's following rivals that of Dalai Lama's

Does it means the same as >Robin sharma's following rivals of Dalai Lama's.

My understanding of above statement is that Robin sharma is trying to convince folks who were not convinced by Dalai Lama. Is that correct ?

Comment: Please look up the word *rival* in the Oxford or Cambridge Dictionary or other professionally compiled dictionary. Hint: *rivals* is a **verb** here.

Comment: This reads like a heading rather than an ordinary sentence; headings can sometimes make less sense because of the restriction on words. In any case, it's poorly worded because it makes the reader work to understand it. You might not have picked that here, "following" is a noun and "rivals" is a verb. This is why "that" is necessary and your understanding is incorrect. It means "The following of Robin Sharma rivals that [i.e. the following] of the Dalai Lama".

Comment: `The following of Robin Sharma rivals that [i.e. the following] of the Dalai Lama` Does it means following of Robin Sharma is increasing and that is giving competition to Dalai lama's following ?

Comment: Classic 'crash blossom'. 'Rivals' is supposed to be a verb but easily understood here as a noun, totally messing up the parse. The intended parsing is 'that of' means the 'following of' the Dalai Lama.

Comment: Robin Sharma has some followers. So does the Dalia Lama. There are many followers of the Dalai Lama, and the number of followers of Robin Sharma are almost as many as those of the Dalia Lama. See [Crash Blossom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only means that the *size* of Robin Sharma's following rivals that of the Dalai Lama (that the sizes are similar). Or it could read like "Robin Sharma's following rivals that of the dalai lama *for size*.

Basically, the word "rivals" is used to mean "can be compared with", in this case, because it is a similar size. Not that they are specific rivals.